# Регулярное выражение (добавление каталога в файловую маску)

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Не соображу, что-то как сделать... 
В общем, имеется переменная, которая содержит строку текста. Нужно в этой строке заменить `*.css` на `template/*.css`.

Answer (score 4):

```
$str = preg_replace('/([^/]+\.css)/', 'template/$1', $str);
```

Comment: Как я понимаю, звёздочка -- элемент строки. Т.е. `$str = preg_replace('/\*\.css/', 'template/$0', $str);`

Comment: Ошибку выдает, но исходя из этого я получил то, что мне нужно, спасибо.

[code]$page = preg_replace("/([-a-zA-Z0-9]+\.css)/", "template/$1",$page);[/code]

Comment: Прошу прощения, скобочки забыл, да

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = str_replace("*.css", "template/*.css", $str);
```